# Which represents T is R's nephew?

Tags: family

Read the given information carefully and answer the questions given below:

- (i)   'A * B' means A 'is brother of B'
- (ii)  'A - B' means A 'is sister of B'
- (iii) 'A + B' means A 'is father of B'
- (iv)  'A / B' means A 'is mother of B'

**Question 1: Which of the following represents 'T is nephew of R' ?**

- (A) $R - K + T$
- (B) $R * K / T$
- (C) $R/ K * T$
- (D) $R - K + T * M$

I feel there is more than 1 correct answer to the question but the answer key says only 1. How many represent the required relationship correctly?

I found this puzzle in a highschool level Reasoning and Aptitude Olympiad here in India that was held in the year 2022.

Comment: Could you provide a link?

Comment: Sorry for that but actually I am having a previous year question booklet for the same. I don't think they have an online version for the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The answer is D because only D gives us the gender of T. All the others work for T being K's niece as well.

Comment: Ohhhhhh so that is the pointttt! Thankssss